# como adicionar uma imagem somente no checkbox marcado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer para adicionar uma imagem com append somente dentro da `span.abcd` que está junto à checkbox marcada.

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="hovereffect">
        <span class="abcd"></span>
        <img id="he" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/350x200" alt="">
        <div class="overlay">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-primary cke">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="nao"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    if($(this.checked)){
       $(".abcd").append('<img id="hea" class="img-responsive" src="../images/heart.png">');
       return;
    }
});
```

Com esse código no momento em que eu clico no `checkbox` ele adiciona a `img` do append em todos os `span` com a classe `abcd` e eu gostaria que ele adiciona-se apenas `span` junto ao checkbox que fosse clicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes usar assim:

```
$(this).closest('.hovereffect').find(".abcd").append(
```

No fundo é teres como ponto de partida o `this`, subires no DOM e procurar a div com classe `.hovereffect` e depois descer com `.find(".abcd")`, e esse é o teu `span`...